# Is there any domain name one could use as a fake malicious website example?

Tags: dns, dns-domain

I'm looking for some domain name whose purpose is to act as a bogus malicious/suspicious/untrusted website or endpoint to be used as an example or in documentation.

IANA has reserved example.com for general purpose, is there an "evil" counterpart run by any organization? Something like "suspicious-website.com" or anything else with an obviously malevolent domain name ?

Comment: Nitpick: "ICANN has reserved example.com for general purpose".  No it is the IETF doing that, not ICANN. See RFC2606 written almost before ICANN ever started to exist.

Comment: Anything .example is reserved in RFC 2606. You could do malicious-website.example. I've seen evil.com used, but that appears to be an actual website.

Comment: "is to act as a bogus malicious/suspicious/untrusted website" This is subjective, not technical. Contrary to reserving `example.com` which is uniform, labeling a website as "untrusted" is a subjective measure coming from one specific provider. Saying otherwise: depending on WHO you ask you may get data back that a domain/website is trusted or not. So for your question you need to ask it to the provider you are using to label websites, you don't mention which one. "obviously malevolent domain name" I would be curious to see how you define "obviously malevolent"... just because of the name?

Comment: Do you need the domain to work?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek As stated, I'm looking for a domain name, I don't care what the website is, or even that there is one.

Comment: @schroeder  One which resolves in the global DNS to some IP which won't mind receiving random traffic. Don't care if there is a server behind it or not.

Comment: That's different. You need it to resolve?

Comment: Have you looked up the RFC 2606 mentioned above? https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2606

Comment: I had some personal domains for this purpose but I recently let them go. I see that they'd been gobbled up already ...

Comment: Yes I have. But I need an actual existing domain name. Of course I could create one myself but if some company or organization already runs one, i'd rather use that.

Comment: "As stated, I'm looking for a domain name, I don't care what the website is, or even that there is one.". I still don't understand. How, on what technical ground, do you consider a domain to be "malicious" just by looking at its name? Again that all depends on the provider deciding which one is malicious or not depending on its criterias.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I just want the name to be obvious. If by looking at "example.com" one expects to find an example website behind it, surely "malicious-website.com" is equally self-explanatory.

Comment: Then why asking? Just use whatever name is "obvious" to you. It seems you already have your own answer.

Comment: Yes but I need it to resolve. And if possible not to log every data it will receive. Do you know one?

Comment: "Yes but I need it to resolve. And if possible not to log every data it will receive." This is completely new requirements you did not put in your question, and you should. This is completely different from "a name being malicious". You can never fully know what the other end logs or not, so if you want this full control you have to do things by yourself, hence create the name you want and make sure it behaves as you need. Also, why you need a second domain? If you have any `foobar.example` domain name already, no need to buy another one, just use `i-am-evil.foobar.example`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if some company or organization already runs one, i'd rather use that

I'm not sure that's a good idea. The benefit of `example.com` is that it is standardized. You can be reasonably certain that it will not change. It will not disappear, it will not start logging requests (if you trust the IANA), it will not serve actually malicious content, etc.

You can't do that for any random domain from some random company.

Though if that doesn't matter to you, you could use any of the existing evil.[com/org/etc] domains.

I'd recommend against it though. Alternative ideas:

- use `example.net` or `example.org` (both are reserved according to [rfc2606](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2606)). Spell it out that `.net`/`.org` is "evil" and `.com` is "good".
- use any of the reserved tlds (`.test`, `.example`, `.invalid`, `.localhost`). Eg `evil.example`. They won't resolve, but it may be good enough for you.
- use a fake subdomain of the reserved `example.com` domain. Eg `good.example.com` vs `evil.example.com` (but again, they will not resolve).

The benefit of any of these is that you can be relatively sure that they will remain as they are (as they are reserved domains/tlds).

Comment: Well that was the purpose of my question. Is there some standardized domain for this purpose maintained by an official organisation? Or at least by a recognized security company which can be trusted (enough)? If not, then I would stick with example.com

Comment: @Bastien No, afaik there is no such thing. There is nothing in the relevant rfcs 2606 or 6761, the IANA page on [reserved domains](https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved), or anything else that comes close to a standardization (that I'm aware of).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the TLD `.evil` used. It's not an official TLD, so it won't work.

So:

- gmail.evil
- paypal.evil
- etc.evil

There may be a chance that it might be added in the future, so I'm not sure how future-proof it might be.

Comment: It doesn't exist in IANA root zone today. It could exist tomorrow, through normal mechanisms, and then you created an ambiguity. RFC2606 puts aside `.example` as TLD to play with, and some others, and there is no reason to invent any other new TLD. Plus, depending on where you plug the name, software may have trouble understanding it is a TLD and hence considering the name to be relative to some base domain name, instead of absolute from the root, so many operational issues can arrive. So in short no advantages and many disadvantages.

Comment: Yep, and I mentioned the downsides. I mention it merely as something I have seen done.

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of things having been done, but not all of them are good ideas :-) Again, even if you put aside the "may be used later", there is the other part: some systems might test the TLD and not seeing it official, consider the full name to be relative and not absolute. Which can create all sorts of havoc.